# what If I want to add some info text between filter and list?

Tags: react-admin

The title says it all.

I can not find a good solution.

what I want to implement is below..

"total 10,000 key found"

[image]

follow is my code

```js
 return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <List
            {...props}
            exporter={false}
            filters={<ComponentFilter choices={productPiNames} />}
            bulkActionButtons={<BulkActionButtons />}
          >
            <Datagrid>
             ...
            </Datagrid>
          </List>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the `<List>` component, but instead use `<ListBase>`, which lets you define the exact layout you want for the list in JSX. For instance:

```
import { 
    Datagrid,
    ListBase,
    ListToolbar,
    BulkActionsToolbar,
    Pagination,
    useListContext,
} from 'react-admin';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';

const PostList = props => (
    <MyList {...props}>
        <Datagrid>
            ...
        </Datagrid>
    </MyList>
);

const MyList = props => (
    <ListBase>
        <h1>{props.title}</h1>
        <ListToolbar
            filters={props.filters}
            actions={props.actions}
        />
        <Card>
            <BulkActionsToolbar>
                {props.bulkActionButtons}
            </BulkActionsToolbar>
            {cloneElement(children, {
                hasBulkActions: props.bulkActionButtons !== false,
            })}
            <Pagination />
        </Card>
    </ListBase>
);
```

Check the ListBase doc in the react-admin doc `<List>` chapter https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#listbase

Comment: thanks. actually I tried that way you suggested. but it didn't work well.. I will try again! thanks for letting me know.